# 2checkout extension does't work with compilation mode enabled?

Tags: magento, compilation, checkout, magento-1.8, 2checkout

I'm using Magento 1.8.1.0 to run my store,I have installed the 2checkout payment gateway extension [http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/2checkout-payment-extension.html] and made the required account configurations

The problem is when I set the compilation mode to disable the 2checkout payment option works fine at the checkout page. but when I try to switch the mode back into enable the 2checkout option disappears?

I have contacted both Magento, and 2checkout company to tell them about this issue. but everyone says this bug happens by the other side.

Did you know how to fix this ? and what if I kept the compilation mode disabled. does it effect any thing in my store?

Comment: Did you recompile again?

Comment: Yes I have, and when I did that the checkout payment method disappears

Comment: Check if the same block gets called from other module or not?

Comment: I flushed the cash for sure. about your last comment can you inform me which process you mean to check if the same block it has been called by other modules?